# Multiple Ajax links on a single page in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following code:

## view

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="job"><%= link_to(job.title, job.url, :target => "_blank") %>
          <a id="add-to-favorites"><i class="fa fa-heart" title="Save to my jobs"></i></a></div>
...
```

## controller

```
  def add_to_favorites
    //I would like to see some params here also
    puts "made it to add_to_favorites"
  end
```

## JS

```
$("#add-to-favorites").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "add_to_favorites",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: {}
                    });
    });
```

## route

```
  get 'add_to_favorites', to: 'jobs#add_to_favorites'
```

Two questions. First, how can I get the click/ajax call for each of the jobs. Right now it only works for the first job on the page. I am guessing this is due to my using `id="add-to-favorites"` for each of the jobs in the view. Should this be a unique id for each job?

Second, how do I pass params to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern about the ids is correct. You should probably include an object id with the id attribute on your element. You can do something like:

```
<%= link_to '#', id: "add-to-favorites-#{job.id}" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-heart" title="Save to my jobs"></i>
<% end %>
```

...but that'll make it difficult to target via JavaScript. You might be better off doing something like this:

```
<%= link_to '#', id: "add-to-favorites-#{job.id}", class: 'some-class', data: {id: job.id} do %>
  <i class="fa fa-heart" title="Save to my jobs"></i>
<% end %>
```

That way you can use the `data-id` attribute to get the id that you need.

```
$(".some-class").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var idToGet = $(this).data('id');
  data = {
    id: idToGet,
    // whatever else you need to pass to your controller as params
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "add_to_favorites",
    type: "GET",
    data: data
  });
});
```

Anything you pass as `data` should show up in your controller as `params`. Also these kinds of things are usually configured to use a `POST` request.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of using `link_to` in this particular case? The link doesn't seem to be doing much of anything.

Comment: The markup in OP's question has a link tag that wraps the `<i>` tag

Comment: Yes, that is true. But, I'm wondering what purpose the link serves.

Answer (score 2):

> Should this be a unique id for each job?

Yes. By definition, there should only be one element on a page with a given `id`. I think I would do something more like:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="job">
            <%= link_to(job.title, job.url, :target => "_blank") %>
            <i class="fa fa-heart add-to-favorites-icon" data-id="<%= job.id %>" title="Save to my jobs"></i>
          </div>
...
```

It's been a long time since I've used `erb`, so you may need to fiddle with that to get the `data-id` set correctly. I've removed the `a` element since it doesn't seem like it is necessary.

Then, I think I would change your `routes.rb` to look more like:

```
resources :jobs do 
  member do 
    post :add_to_favorites
  end
end
```

I believe it is more conventional to use a `POST` HTTP verb for this action since it is is not idempotent. This will give you:

```
add_to_favorites_job POST   /jobs/:id/add_to_favorites(.:format)      jobs#add_to_favorites
                jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)                           jobs#index
                     POST   /jobs(.:format)                           jobs#create
             new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)                       jobs#new
            edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format)                  jobs#edit
                 job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)                       jobs#show
                     PATCH  /jobs/:id(.:format)                       jobs#update
                     PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)                       jobs#update
                     DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)                       jobs#destroy
```

Then, I would change your `js` to look more like:

```
$(".add-to-favorites-icon").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "jobs/#{$(this).data().id}/add_to_favorites",
    type: "POST",
    data: {}
  });
});
```

You may need to fiddle with that a bit.

`$(this)` will refer to the clicked icon and `$(this).data().id` should return the `id` that was set above. The string interpolation with give you a url something like `jobs/1/add_to_favorites` (or whatever the `id` is). Clicking the icon, then, will make a POST call which will route to your `add_to_favorites` action with an `id` param that you can use to look up your `job`.

> how do I pass params to the controller?

To pass params to the controller, use the `data` argument to the `$.ajax` call. Something like:

```
$(".add-to-favorites-icon").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "jobs/#{$(this).data().id}/add_to_favorites",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  });
});
```

This will make a POST call which will route to your `add_to_favorites` action with an `id` param and a `foo` param.

Now, it seems to me that you probably want the favorite icon to act like a toggle. That is, if someone hasn't favorited a job yet, clicking the icon adds the job as a favorite. And if someone has favorited the job, clicking it unfavorites the job. So, you might do something like:

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="job">
            <%= link_to(job.title, job.url, :target => "_blank") %>
            <i class="fa fa-heart <%= current_user.favorited_jobs.include?(job) ? 'favorited' : 'not-favorited' %>" data-id="<%= job.id %>" title="Save to my jobs"></i>
          </div>
...
```

(This, naturally, assumes you can do something like `current_user.favorited_jobs.include?(job)`, which you might have to create. It's just an example.)

You can then use the 'favorited' and 'not-favorited' classes to change the icon color in your `css` so that the user gets some visual feedback about what they've already favorited.

Then change `routes.rb` to:

```
resources :jobs do 
  member do 
    post :add_to_favorites
    post :remove_from_favorites
  end
end
```

And change your `js` to something like:

```
$(".job .not-favorited").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "jobs/#{$(this).data().id}/add_to_favorites",
    type: "POST",
    data: {}
  })
  .done(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('not-favorited').addClass('favorited')
  });
});

$(".job .favorited").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "jobs/#{$(this).data().id}/remove_from_favorites",
    type: "POST",
    data: {}
  })
  .done(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('favorited').addClass('not-favorited')
  });
});
```

Now, clicking the icon will both change the favorited status in your models and change the icon color on your front end (assuming you've twiddled with your `css`).

Comment: This is awesome jvillian...very comprehensive. I went with NM's answer only because I have not added auth yet, but I will come back to your answer when I do.

Comment: Fair enough. Setting aside auth, I would still urge you to consider using `POST` instead of `GET`, reworking your routes, and eliminating the use of the `<a>` (link) element since it doesn't really do anything. Good luck!